# how to pass json object from jquery to mvc view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

At present, I have a list of all todo list items shown in a List view. I also have an Edit hyperlink placed for each row in the list. When I click on Edit, I am calling an Edit action asynchronously using jquery and would like to display the Edit View with the item selected at the bottom of List View page.

Below is the code for List.cshtml -

```
@using MvcToDoListItemsDemo.ViewModels
@model TodoListViewModel

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>  
        <th></th>          
        <th>TodoItem</th>
        <th>Is Completed?</th>
        <th>Target Date</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
        <th>Completed Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>        
    @foreach (var item in Model.TodoListItems)
    {
        <tr>                
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "edit",   @id=item.Id })</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class="delete", @id=item.Id })</td>                
            <td>@item.ActivityDescription </td> 
            <td>@item.IsCompleted </td>
            <td>@item.ActivityDeadLine </td> 
            <td>@item.CreatedDate </td> 
            <td>@item.CompletionDate </td>
        </tr>            
    }                
</tbody>    
</table>    
}
```

below are the Edit actions -

```
public class TodoListController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Edit(int Id = 0)
    {            
        var Item = _dbContext.TodoList.Find(Id);
        if (Item == null)
        {
            return Json("No Data Found", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {                
            return Json(Item,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }            
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
    public ActionResult Edit(TodoListModel listItem)
    {            
        TryUpdateModel(listItem);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry<TodoListModel>(listItem).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else return View(listItem);            
    }
}
```

Below is the javascript that will call above [Httpget] Edit action asynchornously

```
function OnEditClick(e) {
var Id = e.target.id;
if (Id != null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TodoList/Edit',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {Id: Id},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {                
            //How to pass Json result to below Edit View.
        },
        error: function () { alert('Error!'); }
    });
}
}
```

Below is the Edit.cshtml Partial View

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>TodoListModel</legend>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityDescription)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActivityDescription)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsCompleted)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCompleted)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityDeadLine)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActivityDeadLine)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
   </fieldset>
```

So my question is - how do we pass the Json result that we got by asynchronously calling the [HttpGet] Edit action to Edit.cshtml ?

Please advise. Is it possible ?

Comment: really not clear what you want to do with response data

Comment: Your ajax request returns JSON to the `$.ajax` callback, which is fine. So if you manage to call the Edit.cshtml, what do you want to do with the generated HTML? You probably want to forget about JSON and do something like `return PartialView("Edit", Item);` so you get the HTML in the ajax response and use that to fill in a `div` or something.

Comment: My point is I would like to reuse the Edit.cshtml. If we hard-code the html inside the javascript function, it can't be reused anywhere else in my project. So, is it possible to convert the JSON  result to C# Model and pass the Model object to Edit action from Jquery itself ?

Comment: Can someone please reply to my question??

Comment: You misunderstanding ajax. Ajax calls stay on the same page. Instead of using ajax, redirect normally using the link, and in the `Edit` method, return a view rather than JSON. `if(Item == null) { return new HttpNotFoundResult(); } else { return View(Item); }`

Comment: Thanks Stephen. But, the problem is In the List.cshtml, If I click on Edit, then only I would like to display the Edit.cshtml Partial View within the same List.cshtml page. Right now, if I do as per your suggestion, the page will be redirected to separate Edit View page.

Comment: Then keep the ajax, but return a partial view, not JSON. `return PartialView("Edit", Item);` and in the success callback, add the returned result to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it using below code.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "TodoList", new { Id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions
            {
               UpdateTargetId = "EditView",
               HttpMethod = "Get"                  
            })

and return PartialView("Item"); from the controller action.
```